# How to Set ImagesForDates For Specific Dates (08-10-2017) In FsCalendar Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I Already Set Dates On This Method

```
private func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, imageFor date: Date) -> UIImage? {

let day: Int! = self.gregorian.component(.day, from: date)
        return [1,2,3].contains(day) ? UIImage(named: "mens") : nil
 }
```

I would like to set it on this - It doesn't work please help me :)

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, imageFor date: Date) -> UIImage? {
    let day: Int! = self.gregorian.component(.day, from: date)
    return [08-10-2017, 08-11-2017].contains(day) ? UIImage(named: "mens") : nil
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Dávid Pásztor Can Anyone help me? please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let day: Int! = self.gregorian.component(.day, from: date)
```

This line will return you the day. For example : - 08-10-2017 it will return 08.
So, first convert the **date** `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, imageFor date: Date) -> UIImage?` into your dd-MM-yyyy format.

Then use this `return [08-10-2017, 08-11-2017].contains(date) ? UIImage(named: "mens") : nil`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Joseph Mikko Manoza did you get this?

Comment: Yep I get it now thanks for the help and here is my code now and it is perfectly fine now.

Comment: func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, imageFor date: Date) -> UIImage? {
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current;
        let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return datesWithEvent.contains(dateStr) ? UIImage(named: "mens") : nil
    }